# In Dask, how would I remove data that is not repeated across all values of another column?

Tags: pandas, dask, dask-distributed

I'm trying to find a set of data that exists across multiple instances of a column's value.

As an example, let's say I have a DataFrame with the following values:

```
+-------------+------------+----------+
| hardware_id | model_name | data_v   |
+-------------+------------+----------+
| a           | 1          | 0.595150 |
+-------------+------------+----------+
| b           | 1          | 0.285757 |
+-------------+------------+----------+
| c           | 1          | 0.278061 |
+-------------+------------+----------+
| d           | 1          | 0.578061 |
+-------------+------------+----------+
| a           | 2          | 0.246565 |
+-------------+------------+----------+
| b           | 2          | 0.942299 |
+-------------+------------+----------+
| c           | 2          | 0.658126 |
+-------------+------------+----------+
| a           | 3          | 0.160283 |
+-------------+------------+----------+
| b           | 3          | 0.180021 |
+-------------+------------+----------+
| c           | 3          | 0.093628 |
+-------------+------------+----------+
| d           | 3          | 0.033813 |
+-------------+------------+----------+
```

What I'm trying to get would be a DataFrame with all elements **except** the rows that contain a `hardware_id` of `d`, since they do not occur at least once per `model_name`.

I'm using Dask as my original data size is on the order of 7 GB, but if I need to drop down to Pandas that is also feasable. I'm very happy to hear any suggestions.

I have tried splitting the dataframe into individual dataframes based on the `model_name` attribute, then running a loop:

```
models = ['1','1','1','2','2','2','3','3','3','3']
import dask.dataframe as dd

frame_1 = dd.DataFrame( {'hardware_id':['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','d'], 'model_name':mn,'data_v':np.random.rand(len(mn))} )
model_splits = []
for i in range(1,4):
     model_splits.append(frame_1[frame_1['model_name'.eq(str(i))]])

aggregate_list = []

while len(model_splits) > 0:
     data = aggregate_list.pop()
     for other_models in aggregate_list:
          data = data[data.hardware_id.isin(other_models.hardware_id.to__bag())]
     aggregate_list.append(data)

final_data = dd.concat(aggregate_list)
```

However, this is beyond inefficient, and I'm not entirely sure that my logic is sound.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you essentially trying to filter the dataframe to remove all rows where the value in `hardware_id` only occurs once in the entire column?

Comment: @NickBecker Almost: I want to remove all rows where the value in `hardware_id` does not occur at least once for every value in `model_name`.  I'll edit the question to hopefully be a bit more clear.

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that your "keep" condition is that any `hardware_id` must co-occur with every unique value of `model_name`?

Comment: @NickBecker That's exactly it. Thanks, I had a hard time expressing this concept.

Comment: Perfect. I'll throw up a solution shortly. This can be mapped nicely between pandas and dask, but it has to be done a bit differently than you have it in your example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to treat it as a groupby-aggregation problem.

#### Pandas

First, we set up the data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(12)

models = ['1','1','1','2','2','2','3','3','3','3']

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'hardware_id':['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','d'],
     'model_name': models,
     'data_v': np.random.rand(len(models))
    }
)
```

Then, collect the unique values of your `model_name` column.

```py
unique_model_names = df.model_name.unique()
unique_model_names
array(['1', '2', '3'], dtype=object)
```

Next, we'll do several related steps at once. Our goal is to figure out which `hardware_ids` co-occur wiht the entire unique set of `model_names`. First we can do a groupby aggregation to get the unique `model_names` per `hardware_id`. This returns a list, but we want this as a tuple for efficiency so it works in the next step. At this point, every hardware ID is associated with a tuple of it's unique models. Next, we check to see if that tuple exactly matches our unique model names, using `isin`. If it doesn't we know the condition should be False (exactly what we get).

```py
agged = df.groupby("hardware_id", as_index=False).agg({"model_name": "unique"})
agged["model_name"] = agged["model_name"].map(tuple)
agged["all_present_mask"] = agged["model_name"].isin([tuple(unique_model_names)])
agged
    hardware_id model_name  all_present_mask
0   a   (1, 2, 3)   True
1   b   (1, 2, 3)   True
2   c   (1, 2, 3)   True
3   d   (3,)    False
```

Finally, we can use this to get our list of "valid" hardware IDs, and then filter our initial dataframe.

```py
relevant_ids = agged.loc[
    agged.all_present_mask
].hardware_id
​
result = df.loc[
    df.hardware_id.isin(relevant_ids)
]
result
hardware_id model_name  data_v
0   a   1   0.154163
1   b   1   0.740050
2   c   1   0.263315
3   a   2   0.533739
4   b   2   0.014575
5   c   2   0.918747
6   a   3   0.900715
7   b   3   0.033421
8   c   3   0.956949
```

#### Dask

We can do essentially the same thing, but we need to be a little clever with our calls to compute.

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
​
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, 2)
unique_model_names = ddf.model_name.unique()
​
agged = ddf.groupby("hardware_id").model_name.unique().reset_index()
agged["model_name"] = agged["model_name"].map(tuple)
agged["all_present_mask"] = agged["model_name"].isin([tuple(unique_model_names)])
​
relevant_ids = agged.loc[
    agged.all_present_mask
].hardware_id
​
result = ddf.loc[
    ddf.hardware_id.isin(relevant_ids.compute()) # cant pass a dask Series to `ddf.isin`
]
result.compute()
hardware_id model_name  data_v
0   a   1   0.154163
1   b   1   0.740050
2   c   1   0.263315
3   a   2   0.533739
4   b   2   0.014575
5   c   2   0.918747
6   a   3   0.900715
7   b   3   0.033421
8   c   3   0.956949
```

Note that you would probably want to persist `agged_df` and `relevant_ids` if you have the memory available to avoid some redundant calculation.